# Read my free-form date

Tags: code-golf, string, date

Given a date written in any (must handle all in the same program) of the following formats, parse it into a valid `yyyy/mm/dd date`.

```
17th May 2012
March 14th, 2016
20 February 2014
September 14, 2017
Sunday, June 8, 2015
```

**Rules**

- Dates will sometimes be invalid, ie. incorrect day for the month or number of months in a year, you must handle both cases. Either by erroring out or returning a consistent falsey value, you choose. (They will however stick to the template formats above)
- Padding for days and months less than 10 must be used to create a two digit output.
- Month names will always be the full name, not shortened to their three character counterparts.
- You can assume the year will always be within the 0000-9999 range.
- Negative numbers need not be handled.
- You can create a full program or function so output can be in any format, printed to console or returned from a function.
- Input will always be a string, output must always be a string, if it makes it shorter to take it as a single argument in an array eg. `["17th May 2012"]` you may do so and output can be the same `["2012/05/17"]`
- You can assume spelling in input will be correct.

**BONUS:** cos who here doesnt like a challenge ;)

If you can manage to also allow the input formats of `The Fourteenth of March, 2016` or `March the Fourteenth, 2016` you may take an extra **20 bytes** off your code with any final byte counts less than 1 resulting in 1.

Here are the full written numbers for each of the days to avoid any confusion on spelling.

```
First, Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth, Sixth, Seventh, Eighth, Nineth, Tenth, Eleventh, Twelfth, Thirteenth, Fourteenth, Fifteenth, Sixteenth, Seventeenth, Eighteenth, Nineteenth, Twentieth, Twenty First, Twenty Second, Twenty Third, Twenty Fourth, Twenty Fifth, Twenty Sixth, Twenty Seventh, Twenty Eighth, Twenty Nineth, Thirtieth, Thirty First
```

**Test Cases**

```
INPUT                           | Output
17th May 2012                   | 2012/05/17
March 14th, 2016                | 2016/03/14
20 February 2014                | 2014/02/20
September 14, 2017              | 2017/09/14
Sunday, June 8, 2015            | 2015/06/08
1st January 1918                | 1918/01/01

The Fourteenth of March, 2016   | 2016/03/14
March the Fourteenth, 2016      | 2016/03/14
November the Seventeenth, 2019  | 2019/11/17
The Thirtieth of April, 2016    | 2016/04/30

30 February 2014                | Invalid
September 99, 2017              | Invalid
Sunday, June8, 2015             | Invalid

The Thirty First of April, 2016 | Invalid
```

Comment: "You can assume ... there will always be the at least one space between parts of the date". "Dates will sometimes be invalid ...They will however stick to the template formats above". Doesn't `Sunday, June8, 2015` contradict the format?

Comment: [0/10, not freeform enough](https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: "*cos who here doesnt like a challenge*" - when they come in the form of a bonus, mostly all of us don't! And boo-urns to input validation.

Comment: @Timtech I see the confliction, i'll remove the always has a space rule

Comment: I don't see why the input format is so strict. IMHO it would be better to let us pick one.

Comment: sorry, @Mr. Xcoder, i want you to be able to parse any of the formats given without prior knowledge of the format.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I think the entire challenge is to support multiple input formats.. Things like `20 February 2014` are default supported in a lot of date-parsers, but `17th` and `Sunday, June 8, 2015` are a bit more difficult to parse (depending on the language).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I think it's too much fluff, to handle ***5*** different formats. There is not much clever golfing to be done in this case. I personally dislike the task, if the whole point is to make our code have an if-else boilerplate or something.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I never said it was a fun/boring, easy/hard, good/bad code-golf challenge. I'm simply stating that based on what I read in the challenge, the multiple input-format supporting seems to be the main goal of the challenge. I agree it will most likely be an if-else for the five input-formats, or some kind of regex to extract the year, month and day (which is currently my approach).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder  there shouldnt be much if-else going on as far as i can tell, you just need to cleverly parse a date part (day,month or year) from the string and output the three parts in the correct order

Comment: Can we please at least assume that the year always has four digits?

Comment: @Xynos But you're still saying that inputs "will however stick to the template formats above", and only possible error is wrong day for the month/year etc.

Comment: Can output be separated by hyphens (instead of slashes)?

Comment: Is outputting nothing valid for an invalid input?

Comment: Also test case request: `February 29, 2017` and `February 29, 2016`

Comment: Is the day of the week always correct? Would `Thursday, August 25, 2017` be valid? I see submissions ignoring the DOW.

Comment: @BenjaminCuningham Would Sunday, June 8, 2015 be valid? (It was a Monday.)

Comment: 1. Given "You can assume spelling in input will be correct" and that all formats spell out the month names how can there ever be an input that has an incorrect number of months in a year? 2. `Sunday, June8, 2015` in the examples does not fit any of the listed formats as it is missing a space ("They will however stick to the template formats above"), I imagine this is invalid because 2015/06/08 was not a Sunday, but that seems to not be a part of the previously mentioned possible ways for the input to be invalid (which comes back to Benjamin Cuningham's question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Rails, <s>41</s>, <s>37</s> 35 bytes

```
->x{x.to_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')}
```

I don't know of an online interpreter for Rails, but here is a screenshot demonstrating this proc

[image]

Comment: Online interpreter link?

Comment: Does this really work for all the formats in question? :o

Comment: @totallyhuman Added a screenshot showing the results. Unfortunately I don't know of an online interpreter :(

Answer (score 8):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>91</s> <s>89</s> <s>91</s> 56 bytes

```powershell
date("$args"-replace'th|rd|st|(\b.*)day|,')-f yyyy/MM/dd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/PyWxJFVDSSWxKL1YSbcotSAnMTlVvSSjpiilprikRiMmSU9LMyWxskZHXVM3TaESCPR9ffVTUv7//68eXJoHlNJR8CrNS1Ww0FEwMjA0VQcA)

Takes input as a string. Uses a `-replace` to get rid of junk, then uses the built-in `Get-Date` command with the `-f`ormat flag to specify the required `yyyy/MM/dd` format. That string is left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

*Saved two bytes thanks to Mr Xcoder. Saved a huge chunk thanks to TessellatingHeckler's regex golfing.*

Comment: Hey look competitive PowerShell submission!

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Date manipulation is one of PowerShell's strengths.

Comment: [Why do you have all those extraneous spaces?](https://tio.run/##DclBCsIwEEDRq4QiJJGUqiB4BqErTxCcqRFiWmYmlMLcPeZv3uJv647ECXNuDaKgG06RPjyMhFuOb7SSlEBZ1HEt@luLSkXWHaF0JFViXeirHMVDPFzwZ@vHxdijN83zBGBba/ZVS9/BPGtB8wjmdrne7R8)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder "all those" = 2. lol. Thanks!

Comment: You can remove the `''` from the date format, for -2. If you want to stick to your approach, given the "spelling is correct" then you can replace `'th|rd|st|(\b.*)day|,'` and it drops to 56 bytes and handles the same cases. Although I think it's wrong because if you drop the days, you can't pick up the  `Sunday, June8, 2015             | Invalid` case because it was Monday. It should error, but it parses as valid. Not sure what the ruling on that will be, or if others are checking it.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler That's an interesting point. I had interpreted the reason that was invalid was because it was missing a space, since in the valid section there is the same input with the space and it prints the date. I guess we'll see what the OP says. Thanks for the regex golf!

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>73</s> 164+1 bytes

```php
for(preg_match("#(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)#",$d=$argn,$r);$m++<12;)strpos(_.$d,date(F,strtotime($r[2].-$m)))&&printf(checkdate($m,$r[1],$r[2])?"$r[2]/%02d/%02d":E,$m,$r[1]);
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dee4d03ee97cfdd9c116060a3287fe8c4860a39b).

The date check was really expensive: I had to disassemble the date before using a builtin, then try and error on the month name.

Comment: I think you have to support all formats not just one of them?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer it does. But not the bonus formats.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer This does handle all formats.

Comment: This fails for invalid dates. `30 February 2014` returns `2014/03/02`. *Either by erroring out or returning a consistent falsey value, you choose. (They will however stick to the template formats above)*

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder That quite ruins it ...

Comment: I'm very sorry if it can't easily be fixed :'-(

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Awfully expensive fix: +91 bytes. Your comment ineed added to the post. :D

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + parsedatetime library, <s>152</s> <s>139</s> <s>155</s> 153 bytes

Saved 13 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan

Added 16 bytes to handle dates with invalid length days

Saved 2 bytes by removing lambda assignment

```python
lambda s:re.search(f'(^| ){str(h(s)[0].tm_mday)[:2]}[^\d]',s)and time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d',h(s)[0])
import parsedatetime as p,time,re
h=p.Calendar().parse
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFfa4MwFMXf/RQXoZiAmMTaWgs@DfZQ6F76NJwd6UxRqH9IUqhs@@zOBLsJZRA4l9zfPfeQdL0u22Y53NK34cLrU8FBbaUIlODyo0RnDx2/AH8qLVGJFM5oHuj6vS54j7NtmH9nx7ci93yFeVOArupxUsuzKZC3eCWLmiwKz59GsVPVXSs1dFwqUXAtDAhcQeebypfCKdMueOIX0RRcIhxYctBCaQUpZA4AclmsS9jzHkLKQtcH1yihK8JiF/sW2Zv0wCJd@oZaT9Sa0CVh0Z0KKTyLk7xyab2iiYoIDUlI79RBdFrUJyFHP@sWT1xMaDJzO1zHzL0Pu2sjYGPJ1USuCB1Xb@4kUxp2vLF7WcI2hjJKKBvPnVo@pntpG/GQKkl@U837szR/YWYAi9h//rlzbiWYR4eqsaq240wnq0ajGzIX5jchTW0zYzkefgA)

Does not support bonus dates

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first post. Save [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZdFBa4MwFAfwu5/iIRQjBJNYW2vB02CHQnfpaXTdiDNFoUZJUqhs@@zOBN0KhcALyS8vf5KuN1Url8MtfxsuvClKDnqrRKQFV58VOgfo/RvCrwrp8EhPkWk@mpL3PwHWIZclmLoZrVFnO0HB4pUsGrIoAzwdCL266VploONKi5IbYSFwDR22M6yEV@Vd9MQvQpZcoTBycjBCGw05HD0A5LPUVLDnPcSUxT4G31ZCV4Slfogd2du8wBJTYavWk1oTuiQsmVVM4VkU6sqV65VMKiE0JjGd1UF0RjSFUGM/1y2dXEpodtftcB0z9xh2Vylg4@RqkitCx6s3s2TawI5Ldy/L2MYqWwll45jV8jHdSyvFQ6os@0t1v3@X5j/MBE7euVVgXxVq6arejqc6VUuDbsgu2O@CPHebR3YKh18) by using: the falsey return value of `None`; `import ...as`; & a `lambda` by reusing `parse` as `h`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 193 bytes

```python
lambda s:time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d',time.strptime(re.sub(r'^(\w+) (\d+)',r'\2 \1',re.sub('^ ','',re.sub('(th|rd|st)|(Sun|Mon|Tues|Wednes|Thurs|Fri|Satur)day|,','',s))),'%d %B %Y'))
import re,time
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU9Na8MwDL37V4hCsE2zts669QN62aGHQk8tjLKs4CwOMTROkBVGwf@9Sz3GLttJT3pPT0/dlerWZbdqk98uuilKDX5NtjETT1jdgeDJaZo006Tk6Q/RRQIH3BcC@Vnkn2MJIi/HkqfI8wxyNYBvnp@Bp/y3FVQHLIMnGcShd2HfunDsjQ@vpnRDOdY9@rBFGw6aepSlvoY0OngpZcqTEpIXSE5cSmabrkUCNDHajYwnDxsYjUZMLaiGvb5CNlMZ22v8qEHNqU7vg2eWzWBrCuw1RsWcHUxHpikMDqqoWbAh3XA8hV3vDCzj8IkpT7DTLi6qlVqyx/@dVqs/nH6MhpBvav2g3hmrWgQL1kF8YOK7iyXBc8flGjq0jqASVt6@AA)

;-; pls halp

Comment: *;-; pls halp* - [192 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY9Pa8MwDMXv/hSiEGxTr62zbv0DvezQQ6GnFkZZVnAWhwQaJ8gKo@Dv3qUeY5ftJOmnp8dTd6Wqdemt3GS3i2nywoBf08QTllQ3VvDkNE2aaVJwFWkXKdqJ73OB/Cyyz7EEkRVjyRXyLIVMD833np@BK/47CqoCFsGTDOLQu7BvXTj21odXW7ihHKsefdhiHQ6GepSFuQYVHbyUUvGkgOQFkhOXktVN1yIBWnVPBMYD3ch68rCB0WjE9IIq2JsrpDOdsr3Bjwr0nCp1B88sncHW5tgbjIo5O9iObJNbHFRRs2BDxCGBgl3vLCwjfGLaE@yMi4d6pZfs8X@n1eoPpx@jIeSbXj/od8bKFqGG2kF8YOK7S02CZ47LNXRYO4JS1PL2BQ) by declaring `time`.

Comment: [186 bytes (remove `f=` from the byte count on TiO) by declaring `re.sub`](https://tio.run/##dY/NasMwEITveoolYCQRNYnctPmBXHrIIZBTAiXUDci1jE1i2azWlIDePXUEvbWnXYZvZme7G1WtS@/3uulaJECrqG4sGA/Eys3VNHlhwKvLBu3E9/maJp6wfDCCJ6dp0kyTgquodlG9CORnkX2PJYisGEuukGcpZJqri@Bn4IrHTVAVsAieZBCH3oV968Kxtz6828IN41j16MMW63Aw1KMszC2oaPZSSsWTApI3SE5cyjtZTx42MBqNmF5QBXtzg3SmU7Y3@FWBnlOlHsIrS2ewtTn2BiMxZwfbkW1yiwMVmQUb6gzXFOx6Z2EZxRemPcHOuGjUK71kz/8nrVZ/JP0GDSU/9PpJfzJWtgg11A7iAxPfXWsSPHNcrqHD2hGUopb3Hw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 190 + 26 = 216 bytes

```java
import java.time.format.*;

s->DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM/dd").format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[EEEE, ][d ]MMMM [d, ]uuuu").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT).parse(s.replaceAll("(\\d)[a-z].","$1")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVJdb9owFH3nV1xFQ7Kr4BLajVLWStNWpFaKVDW8pTyY2JTQ4ET2DV028duZccKXqk3dfUhsH597zvW9C77inbyQaiFeN@myyDXCwp4xTJeSzXK95MjOhq2inGZpAknGjYGQpwp@twCaU4Mc7W@VpwKWFiMR6lS9xBPg@sVQdxXqtCWmGZuVKsE0V2zULL7WBL/@3Yqbjenc/uAox9bFyJlAqVk@e3QLRbzSxnkYngvh0cYm@SchvrPhwyQWMAltQCzsbpvGJnhLcf4kTZ6tpI6wyiQ52bFo/HT/fUxZwbWRxDAti4wn8luWEY88Pwsa886vCfN871PgUUo34GLo6t4/BkqDBm6a59iGF/Rxbp@zgl436Hn@AQi5TuYQXOLc32JfjrFeF0ZyqkuuHe/yGItkgXI5ldpyHbN/kjVXglc@PJRKwpXDP5@wy//A@@/xwCA8cOWcBYPg6sS1En/FLj5U0WDwvqJjRzvDDboettzKTkczkK4D13Uf6L4NaEUPLYkqY@VYXiIrLAdnxGt3LrrmGtqmrTzfsX0QjBdFVpHtjjLMawFC6XCnDglH20Jy9zOxFdghB0k/pHOvVjxLxV5snxJA1ncj5MnrWNsJJAe91u67bq03fwA)

**Important note:** it was *shorter* to also validate the day of week instead of ditching it, so that validation is included!

I haven't tried with `SimpleDateFormat` beyond the obvious cases which all accepted dates like 30 February. So I had to ditch it and I used Java 8's `DateTimeFormatter`.

### Explanation

```java
"[EEEE, ][d ]MMMM [d, ]uuuu"
```

This format means :

- optional day-of-week followed by comma and space `[EEEE, ]` (happens in `Sunday, ...`),
- followed by optional day with space `[d ]`,
- followed by month in full letters `MMMM` and space,
- followed by optional day with comma and space `[d, ]`,
- followed by year of era `uuuu` to let the parser know we're in Gregorian era.

Code:

```java
import java.time.format.*;                                     // Required for DateTimeFormatter, *and* ResolverStyle

s->DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM/dd")                   // Output format
  .format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[EEEE, ][d ]MMMM [d, ]uuuu")  // Input format
      .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)                 // Invalidates xxxx-02-30 instead of transforming it into xxxx-02-28
      .parse(
        s.replaceAll("(\\d)[a-z].","$1")                       // remove st, nd, rd, th
       )
    )
```

## Credits

- 2 bytes in the regex thanks to Neil.

Comment: Do you need the brackets in the `replaceAll` pattern?

Comment: Looks like I don't. Thanks, @Neil!

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>124</s> 122 bytes

```js
f=
s=>(d=new Date(s.replace(/.[dht]\b/,'')+' +0')).getDate()==s.match(/\d\d?/)&&d.toISOString().replace(/-(..)(T.*)?/g,'/$1')
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Comment: Returns `2015/06/07` for `June 8, 2015` (UTC issue? I'm in UTC+2)  and `false` for either `Sunday, June 8, 2015` or `Monday, June 8, 2015`.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks for pointing those out. I'd only tried dates in UK outside Summer Time so they were already using UTC, and I'd not tried weekdays ending in `nday`.